# Expected value of the distance to the center of a cube

Tags: probability

assume $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ are three independent variables with uniform distribution on (-1,1)

what is the expected value of $\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2}$?

My thought is that since they are independent, it is equivalent to calculate the expected value of $\sqrt{3X_1^2}$, which really means to calculate the expected value of $\sqrt{3|X_1|}$

> Am i correct?　any hint is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: E(sqrt(x)) differs from sqrt(E(x)) in general, so I think your answer is wrong.

Comment: yea i know but i didn't say they are equal. What i suggest is that E(sqrt(x1^2+x2^2+x3^2))=E(sqrt(3X1^2)). is that correct?

Comment: No: since $\sqrt{X_1^2+X_2^2+X_3^2}\ne\sqrt{3X_1^2}$, there is no reason to believe their expectations are the same.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a computer algebra system to do the nitty gritties for you? In this instance, the joint pdf of $(X,Y,Z)$ is $f(x,y,z)$:

[image]

and the expectation you seek is:

[image]

where `Expect` is a function from the `mathStatica` add-on to *Mathematica* (I should add I am one of the authors of the former ... but equally I am sure other packages could also do this). The answer is approximately 0.960592.

By contrast, $E[\sqrt{3 X^2}] = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  \approx 0.866$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\large\tt Hint:$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1}{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}{1 \over 2}\int_{-1}^{1}{1 \over 2}\,
\root{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}z
=
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}
\root{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}}\,{\rm d}x\,{\rm d}y\,{\rm d}z
\end{align}

Comment: Seriously, do you think this answers the question?